# Java Double get all Digits after dot/comma

Tags: java

it´s a simple task but i´m not able to solve it on my own..

i got

```
    double digit1 = 12.1;
    double digit2 = 12.99;
```

and need a method which gives me this:

```
    anyMethod(digit1); //returns 10
    anyMethod(digit2); //returns 99
```

what i have is

```
public static void getAfterComma(double digit) {

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(( digit - Math.floor( digit )) * 100 );
    bd = bd.setScale(4,RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
    System.out.println(bd.toBigInteger()); // prints digit1=1 and digit2=99

}
```

anyway i prefer integer as the returntype..
anybody got a quick solution/tip?

kindly

Comment: `10` is not *all* digits of `12.1` after the dot. What exactly is your requirment?

Comment: What about 12.10? And what about 12.123?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not you simply use:

```
int anyMethod(double a){
  //if the number has two digits after the decimal point.
  return (int)((a + 0.001) * 100) % 100;
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't work for many arguments - for example, anyMethod(0.29) returns 28.999999999999996

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman - fair enough, but IMHO, those aren't corner cases - it's a fundamental flaw in trying to use floating point arithmetic in this way.  The updated version doesn't work either - the new anyMethod(0.15) returns 14.

Comment: The problem with the last case failing may be because the mod operation is done on the *float* result and then cast to an int. I suggest `((int)Math.round(a*100)) % 100`.

Answer (score 8):

A simple way of getting the fractional part of a `double` is to use the modulo operator, `%`.  However, you'll have to take into account the fact that floating point arithmetic isn't precise.  For example,

```
System.out.println(12.1 % 1);   // outputs 0.09999999999999964
System.out.println(12.99 % 1);  // outputs 0.9900000000000002
```

If you want to get two decimal digits as an `int`, which is what I think you're asking, you can achieve this, glossing over the floating point issues, like so:

```
System.out.println(Math.round((12.1 % 1) * 100));   // outputs 10
System.out.println(Math.round((12.99 % 1) * 100));  // outputs 99
```

However, you should consider going further down the `BigDecimal` path you started down, which uses arbitrary precision arithmetic.  You could do something like this:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("12.1").remainder(BigDecimal.ONE));   // outputs 0.1
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("12.99").remainder(BigDecimal.ONE));   // outputs 0.99
```

If, as before, you want two decimal digits from this, you can do this:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("12.1").remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).multiply(new BigDecimal(100)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).intValue());   // outputs 0.1
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("12.99").remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).multiply(new BigDecimal(100)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).intValue());   // outputs 0.99
```

Note that there a couple of differences between these last two methods and the first two: they preserve the sign of the argument, so if you use the final example for -12.99, you'll get -99 back, and they treat the fractional part of an integer as 1, so if you use the final example for 12, you'll get 100 back.

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary to use `Number` tyeps all the time. You can take advantage of `String` as a mediator.

```
String mediator = Double.valueOf(d1).toString();
mediator = mediator.substring(mediator.indexOf('.') + 1);
Integer result = Integer.valueOf(mediator);
```

Comment: thats what i have.. i throw 1.99 in an get 99 .. but even if i compute 1.9 it give me 9 and i want to have 90!

Comment: @AlexTape, What about 12.123? What do you want it to return?

Comment: Try `String.format("%.2f", d1);` as your mediator. It will give you the two digits you're after...

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
        double a=12.99;
        double b=12.1;


        System.out.println(method(a));
        System.out.println(method(b));
    }

    private static int method(double a) {
        return (int) ((a*100)%100);

    }
```

Comment: hehe fine.. but there is still an 0,xx in the result.. i only need 99 and 10! ;) and even the 12 is unkown.. it was a example for any number.. e.g. 1.84 and 599.63 => result should be 84 and 63!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to return `n` digits after the dot for a given `double` number. So... let's see:

```
public int decimalDigits(double x, int n) {
    double ans;
    ans = (x - (int) x) * Math.pow(10, n);
    return (int) ans;
}
```

Done. Hope this helps you.

---

For your specific example, 'n = 2' should do.

Comment: with x = 12.9 and n = 2 it returning 0 but i need 90!

Comment: @AlexTape Sorry, my mistake... I've corrected my answer. Now it should work

Answer (score 0):

sachin-pasalkar done it! little fix but fine!

```
public static int anyMethod(double a){
      return (int) (a*100)%100;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this code returns digits after '.' always. Without any extra parameters other than double variable.

```
public int anyMethod(double d)
{
    String numString = d+"";
    return Integer.parseInt(numString.substring(numString.indexOf('.')+1));
}
```